# CSS Moving divs under other divs

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with some div-elements in my metro dashboard.
A sample of my code are in the snippet below.

Is there any way to move tile 4 and 5 under 2 and 3 to fill this empty room.

```css
.tile-group-4x2 {
   width: 216px;
   height: 108px;
}

.tile-1x1 {
     margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     background: #67D4FF;
     float: left;
}
   
.tile-2x2 {
     margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
     height: 104px;
     width: 104px;
     background: #67D4FF;
     float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile-group-4x2">
    <div class="tile-2x2">1</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">2</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">3</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">4</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">5</div>
</div>
<p>
Is there any way to move tile 4 and 5 under 2 and 3 to fill this empty room.
</p>
<div class="tile-group-4x2">
    <div class="tile-1x1">2</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">3</div>
    <div class="tile-2x2">1</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">4</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: its done through any way or any fix way to move div in blank space @tomtoxx_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible indeed. So for the class `tile-2x2` I added the classes `right` and `left`. `right` has the `float:right` and `left` `float:left`. So just add left or right in the HTML, and you're good to go.

```css
.tile-group-4x2 {
   width: 216px;
   height: 108px;
}

.tile-1x1 {
     margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     background: #67D4FF;
     float: left;
}
   
.tile-2x2 {
     margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
     height: 104px;
     width: 104px;
     background: #67D4FF;
     float: left;
}
.left{
  float:left;
}
.right{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile-group-4x2">
    <div class="tile-2x2 left">1</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">2</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">3</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">4</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">5</div>
</div>
<p>
Is there any way to move tile 4 and 5 under 2 and 3 to fill this empty room.
</p>
<div class="tile-group-4x2">
    <div class="tile-1x1">2</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">3</div>
    <div class="tile-2x2 right">1</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">4</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@tomtoxx_ Your solutions is here

```css
.tile-group-8x4 {
   width: 216px;
   height: 108px;
}

.tile-1x1 { 
     margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     background: #67D4FF;
     float: left;

}
   
.tile-2x2 {
     margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
     height: 104px;
     width: 104px;
     background: #67D4FF;
     float: right;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="tile-group-8x4">
    <div class="tile-2x2">1</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">2</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">3</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">4</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">5</div>
</div>
<p>
Is there any way to move tile 4 and 5 under 2 and 3 to fill this empty room.
</p>
<div class="tile-group-8x4">
    <div class="tile-1x1">2</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">3</div>
    <div class="tile-2x2">1</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">4</div>
    <div class="tile-1x1">5</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: I guess, he wants to achieve that the first big tile is one the left and the 2nd one on the right. By adding just `float:right` both of the big tiles are on the right.